# GLSL program debugging

Tags: opengl, glsl

```
#ifdef GL_ES                                
precision lowp float;                        
#endif                                        

varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;                        
varying vec2 v_texCoord;                            
varying vec2 v_texCoordBlendMap;                    
varying vec3 v_normal;                              

varying vec4 v_FogColor;                    
varying float v_distance;                     
uniform sampler2D u_texture;                      
uniform sampler2D u_tex1;                    
uniform sampler2D u_tex2;                     
uniform sampler2D u_tex3;                     
void main()                                    
{                                                
 vec4 colour1    = texture2D(u_texture,          v_texCoord); 
vec4 colour2    = texture2D(u_tex1,      v_texCoord);  
float blendVal = texture2D(u_tex2,       v_texCoordBlendMap).r; 
float fValue = 1.0 - blendVal; 
vec4 texColor  = colour1*fValue +   colour2*blendVal; 
texColor.a = 1;                 
v_fragmentColor.a = 1;          
vec4 finalclr = texColor * v_fragmentColor; 
    if(finalclr.a == 1)         //why not it equal 1        
        {                                       
        gl_FragColor=vec4(1,0,0,1);         
     }                                      
     else                                   
     {                                      
        gl_FragColor=vec4(1,1,1,1);         
    }                                       
}
```

hi,guys  ，sorry about asking it on cellphone。I'm being puzzled by debugging blender script in this week.  the above ps script it was used for moduling two RGBA.but for testing and simplification,i 'm writing two Alpha channel  to be 1.0 intentionally and expecting red colour of output.but the frag colour output is white instead of red colour. how could it be?

Comment: equality tests on floating point data are always a bad idea

Comment: @derhass normally I'd agree with you, but they're essentially multiplying 1 by 1 and it would appear not getting 1. There are no circumstances under which multiplying 1 by 1 should not give 1, and this equality test is fine in this case.

Comment: That said, I'd verify that the `else` is getting called. I've seen many cases where setting up other OpenGL state leads to an all white output. Verify that it really is taking the `else` by changing the white to green or something. If it is, then my money is on `v_fragmentColor` not being writeable.

Comment: If you read the specification, it tells you that no precision of **`int`** is representable by `lowp` **`float`**. I would use floating-point constants instead of integer constants, even though the concept of integer representation actually refers to the representable range (`lowp` **int** = -2^8 - 2^8, `lowp` **float** = 2.0^-8 - 2.0). It is good to understand that `lowp` float limits you to +/- **2.0** anyway, a lot of people are completely unaware of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try narrowing it down a bit more with:

```
finalclr.a = texColor.a * v_fragmentColor.a;
```

It could very well be that:

- the vector multiplication operator may not be what you are expecting
- the vector multiplication is introducing floating point inaccuracies.
- the float multiplication is introducing floating point inaccuracies.
- `v_fragmentColor` is not writeable.
- fragment shaders get a default medium precision AFAIK, you might have to supply `precision highp` precision specifier

If it comes down to a precision issue you cant get around, compare the difference of floats `a` and `b` using something like:

```
if (abs(a - b) < EPSILON) // absolute value of difference
{
    // consider them equal...
}
```

where `EPSILON` is some small value.

Comment: It occurs to me that it pretty much *can't* be a precision issue. If you think about how floating point numbers work, the number 1.0 *has* to be exactly representable.

Comment: @Preet Kukreti，thank your reply.could you please tell me why v_fragmentColor is not writeable.

Comment: What is more, fragment shaders are not even required to support `highp`. You need to make a habit of checking the pre-processor definition: `GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH` before ever declaring anything `highp` in a fragment shader.